# Casting result.event into an ArrayCollection of Person (Class) in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, arraycollection, resultevent

Im kinda new to the Flex environment and I was wondering how to do this scenario:

My initial code goes like this:

```
public function displayAllNames(event:ResultEvent):void {

    var result:ArrayCollection  = new ArrayCollection();

    result = event.result as ArrayCollection;

   if (result.length != 0){
       listBox.dataProvider = result;
   }
}
```

**event.result** is an ArrayCollection of Person class that has the name attribute

**listBox** is the id of the List Component in Flex where the names are going to be displayed

When I tried to run the code, the listbox did show something. But instead of the names, it displayed **object Object** all throughout. It seems like I still have to do something with *event.result* first so that it would be an ArrayCollection of Person class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the labelField of your ComboBox, try this

Assuming Person has a visible name property,

```
public class Person(){
   public var name:String = "User 1";
}
```

You can tell your ListBox to use that property to populate its label field by using the `labelField` property

```
if (result.length != 0){
   listBox.labelField = "name";
   listBox.dataProvider = result;
}
```

By default I believe is set to `"label"`, if that property is not found it will use `Object.toString()` that's where `[Object object]` is coming from.

due to this its also possible to override, or simply include, the `toString` method in your data provider class and not change the list's `labelField`

```
overide pubic function toString():String{
    return "this will become your label field";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by listBox.labelField = "name";? What does it do?

Comment: It tells the list box to use name property on your collection objects as the label filed

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but its still doing the same thing. It's still displaying [object Object] on the listBox.

Comment: Can you add some more code, include the Object class and how it is being added to your array collection.